# How to create charts in Drupal while working offline that integrate with the Quiz module?

Tags: 6, quiz, charts, log-messages

I'm now working on a local offline network website, which needs a graphical chart report for their quiz. But since it's offline I cannot use the (interactive) [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) API as a charting engine.

I tried [FusionCharts](https://www.drupal.org/project/fusioncharts) already for the [Webform Report](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_reports) module, but it has no integration with [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz).

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Flot](http://drupal.org/project/flot) since it has views integration as Quiz.
[Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) can be used offline while Google charts can't because of their [TOS](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#offline).

Comment: I give it a try and let you know if it works, thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Possible options

To create charts in Drupal, have a look at the [Comparison of charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) as a possible place to start from, to find the module that best fits your needs. That comparison includes quite some charting modules ... and related [charting libraries](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#supportedlibraries) (engines).

## Options to be eliminated

Possible alternatives that for sure will **not** solve this specific question (= illustrate the "pain"?), are the [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module, or the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module. Because the D6 version of both modules require an internet connection.

However, for somebody using D7, using the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module in combination with the Highcharts library could work, provided you have a valid license for it (which is free for non-commercial use).

## License requirements

The **license** that comes with the related charting library (engine) in each of these charting modules, should be considered also. It is one of the (important?) selection criteria for deciding on the module to go for. Some other typical items to consider are:

- Possible privacy concerns.
- Yes or no support for saving charts in PDFs (usually supported by PHP based libraries, and not supported by JS based libraries).
- Flash based libraries should be avoided if charts are to be displayed on mobile devices.
- Some libraries (like the Google flavors ...) require a working internet connection (not always available in local DEV environments ...).

## Recommended charting libraries

In this specific case, I think you should go for a PHP or JS based library (assuming you have a way to get the library downloaded) and consider one of the modules using [pChart](http://www.pchart.net/) or [SVG Graph](http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php) (both open source).

## Examples

Here are some online examples created with either of these libraries:

- The [SVG Graph demo](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.svg_demo) uses the [SVG Graph](http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php) library. It's created by the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module, which you can use to create your own custom charts.
- The [Days of week](http://drupal.placeto.be/visitors/days_of_week) example uses the [pChart](http://www.pchart.net/) library. It's created by the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) module and can be used as an example of "roll your own cookies" without using a typical charting module (by looking at its [source code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/visitors/tree/visitors.chart.inc?h=7.x-1.x)).

**Be aware**: I'm a (co-)maintainer of all modules mentioned, and the author of the [Comparison of charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985).